# Why kafka the size of last log segment reduce when producer stop after a while?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to benchmark for kafka producer, 
and i found the size of the last log segment reduce when producer stop after a while.
see the example `00000000000005746692.log` below:

```
2020-05-23 08:40:35    /bin/du /data/kafka/json_test-0 -a
...
4   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.snapshot
1048704 /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.log
68  /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.index
104 /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.timeindex
4   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.snapshot
258176  /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.log
10240   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.index
10240   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.timeindex
6571068 /data/kafka/json_test-0


2020-05-23 08:40:38    /bin/du /data/kafka/json_test-0 -a
...
4   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.snapshot
1048464 /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.log
68  /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.index
104 /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000004793445.timeindex
4   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.snapshot
222224  /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.log
10240   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.index
10240   /data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.timeindex
6534876 /data/kafka/json_test-0
```

The size of `/data/kafka/json_test-0/00000000000005746692.log` from `258176` reduce to `222224`.

Why kafka the size of last log segment reduce when producer stop after a while?

Edit:

kafka version: `kafka_2.12-2.0.1`

producer's `compression.type`: `snappy`

I doubt this `log.preallocate` configuration [KIP-20](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-20+-+Enable+log+preallocate+to+improve+consume+performance+under+windows+and+some+old+Linux+file+system), but `config/server.properties` not define this properties, it default to `false` [log.preallocate](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#log.preallocate)

Data will be compressed by the producer, written in compressed format on the server and decompressed by the consumer.[Compression](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression)

Comment: Are you using compression.type in your Producer?

Comment: Yes, `compress.type` is `snappy`

Comment: It seem that not producer problem, producer will compress data and send to broker, and broker will not compress the data.

Comment: If you have compaction on at the broker end, I think from memory a background process will go through and remove superseded data, I can't remember exact details now of what is classed as superseded, and whether this does happen within a log segment so this is not an answer but maybe a pointer for something to look at in the documentation.

Comment: There are the retention time and retention size configurations. If your log is older than retention time data, it will be removed. Also,could be associated with this.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes I ’m sure this topic has not reached the time and size.(It is default value, i haven't change it, see that example, that is the last file.)

Comment: @Chris Data will be compressed by the producer, written in compressed format on the server and decompressed by the consumer.[Documention](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression)

Comment: Yes, that's right CHC, and never decompressed by the broker, so I'm not sure if log compaction could happen if clients use compression - definitely worth looking up log compaction in the documentation though

Comment: @Chris  I found related documents, and server side log compaction only enable when i set key, my producer only send message without key. "Log compaction ensures that Kafka will always retain at least the last known value for each message key within the log of data for a single topic partition.[LogCompaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction)"